# python urllib.parse doesn't preserve the path part

Tags: python

```
In [26]: urllib.parse.urljoin("http://example.com/api", "bcd/efg")
Out[26]: 'http://example.com/bcd/efg'
```

Is this expected? 
How can I preserve the `/api` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a forward slash at the end of the 1st segment:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urljoin("http://example.com/api/", "bcd/efg")
'http://example.com/api/bcd/efg'
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/07791ae9b0?runMode=console)